# What causes this very unusual SMTP error?

Tags: smtp, office365

Sending SMTP mail via an Office 365 mail server, using .NET `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` I'm getting the following error:

```
The server response was: 4.3.21 Mailbox server busy; mail intentionally delayed
```

I can't find any reference to this specific code anywhere - the closest thing I can find is [4.3.2 mailbox busy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/remote-server-returned-mailbox-busy)

It seems to be a transient error, but I'm getting a lot of them.

Any idea what the code means?

Comment: Any 4.x.x result code means "try again later". If the remote server is Exchange, the actual message is unusually clear, but that probably means they are actually lying (this is Microsoft, after all). More seriously, perhaps they have internal congestion, and the server is busy. In any event, there is nothing you can do from the outside to make it recover (or in this case perhaps just "cover").

Comment: Was this fixed somehow? I am trying to figure it out as well for thunderbird. Have tried everything, but still not working